# How to convert strings of the format "6 Dec, 2022 " to a date?

Tags: javascript

In python, I used the following:

`datetime.strptime("date in this format", "format, for example %a, %d %b %Y %X %z")`

How can such a problem be solved in js?

Comment: Did you have an issue when you tried? Do you know the `Date` constructor in JavaScript?

Comment: @useren you can just new Date('6 Dec, 2022') in JavaScript